# Laravel- How to check difference between two time stamps using Carbon

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I'm currently working in laravel 5.4 and I need to calculate difference between two available timestamps using Carbon Class. But I'm getting this error `Call to a member function diffInHours() on string` any insights from you people would be helpful thank you :)

User Controller

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
 use EncryptDecrypt;
 public function resetPassword($token)
 {
    $decryptTS = trim($this->decryptText($token));
    $split = explode('-', $decryptTS, 2);

    $userId = $split[0];
    $timeStamp = $split[1];
    $timeStamp1=Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($timeStamp)->toDateTimeString();
    $now = Carbon::now();


    if($timeStamp1->diffInHours($now) <=24)
    {
        echo "valid URL";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid URL";
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this line :

```
$timeStamp1=Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($timeStamp)->toDateTimeString();
```

with :

```
$timeStamp1=Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($timeStamp);
```

this first one will return string not a carbon object